# Azure SQL Performance Optimization - How can I find the code that is running the 'worst offender' queries?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-sql-database, sqlperformance

So I have an Azure SQL database running behind an Asp.NET MVC web application.

The azure portal has come a long way, and now I can do some performance analysis on my SQL server, to see which queries are the worst offenders.

We can see here that there are some quite long running queries.
[image: wow that's long]

And we can get some query Id's out of that, which even give me a breakdown of how the query is constructed.

Some of them I can definitely identify just by looking at the SQL, but some of this code is obfuscated by the linq libraries to the point of me having no idea where it came from. The worst offender being one of those.

Is there a way I can find out which of my code is running these very long running SQL queries?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can find out which of my code is running these very long running SQL queries?

EF doesn't send SQL Server any information about the code that generated the query, but you can capture the queries with [EF Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception), and add them to a log that also contains method calls.  You should be able to generate a log that contains the queries and method names in a test environment.

Or you can do the logging in production, or perhaps use [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestions. I'll give those a try.